# display gnu diff in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, diff

Is there a lib i can use to diff between two pieces of code and display it in html? I am using `diff - GNU diffutils version 2.7`, C#, asp.net. I dont mind the code being in javascript.

I would like just the output with color text + css. I'll build the page around it. Does anyone know a suitable lib?

Answer (score 1):

DiffPlex - http://diffplex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NetBeans, you can go to Tools > Diff > Select the two files to create a patch.

Once you have the generated patch and once you have it open, go to File > Print to HTML > Print To File > OK.

Open the HTML, and edit the CSS.

For example, if you want the GitHub-style background colors red and green, use this:

```
/* Removed text. */
.status-bar-bold
{
    background-color: #ffdddd; /* Pippin red. */
    color: #000000; /* Black. */
}

/* Added text. */
.added
{
    background-color: #ddffdd; /* Snowy mint green. */
    color: #000000; /* Black. */
}
```